# DB2 showing 0 instead of decimal place

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to calculate milliseconds into seconds for a field. I was using `[field]/1000` and that works as long as the value is greater than `1`. Once its under ``1 I get `0`. So if the value is `460` I get `0` instead `0.46`.

I tried the below:

```
RUNTIME/1000 as test,
CAST(RUNTIME/1000 as DECIMAL(5,2)) as test2
```

Comment: What about `RUNTIME/1000.00 as test`? (Not too familiar with db2, so this is an educated guess)

Comment: that worked! i just need to figure out how to round it because i am getting .460000000000

Comment: Look at the "Decimal arithmetic in SQL" topic at the link I provided in my answer. Try `dec(runtime, 29)/1000`. The result type is `dec(31, 2)` in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to the [Expressions](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000736.html) article.

> **Two integer operands**
>
> If both operands of an arithmetic operator are integers, the operation
>   is performed in binary and the result is a large integer unless either
>   (or both) operand is a big integer, in which case the result is a big
>   integer. **Any remainder of division is lost**. The result of an integer
>   arithmetic operation (including negation by means of a unary minus
>   operator) must be within the range of the result type.